# How to rename the preview pdf file name on the browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf

How to set a name for the pdf file that opening online ?
Also here is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Preview1()
    {

  WebClient client = new WebClient();
  var fileStream = client.OpenRead("https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf");

  return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");

    }
```

when I open this method , I got the file name in the browser tab is same as method name "preview1" , and I don't like that actually , if there is a method to change that please help me with that and thanks a lot :)

Comment: Setting `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", new ContentDisposition { FileName = "....", Inline = true }.ToString());` should work

Comment: @stephen-muecke I added it after the var filestream , and not working

Comment: *same as method name "preview1"* - so rename the method...

Answer (score 0):

Set the FileDownloadName property.

```
var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(fs, "application/pdf");
fileStreamResult.FileDownloadName = "Set your document filename here";
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Your Code is working for download not for online preview